# Cannot take a view out and make it work - Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

Im trying to follow along in a tutorial and I am having a problem with the action after clicking the button. To debug, I cleaned my code of everything apart from the action itself and it still doesn't work... Could you help? Its probably something simple:

```swift
import Foundation

class UserInfo: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var test = "test"
    
}
```

And the view:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userInfo: UserInfo = UserInfo()
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack{
            Text(userInfo.test)
            Button(action: {
                self.userInfo.test = "passed"
            }) {
                Text("Log in")
            }
            .font(.title)
            .padding(5)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.top, 10)
            }
    }
}
```

Above code will work fine. But when I try to make new view:

```swift
struct NewView: View {
    @StateObject var userInfo: UserInfo = UserInfo()
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack{
            Text("test")
            Button(action: {
                self.userInfo.test = "passed"
            }) {
                Text("Log in")
            }
            .font(.title)
            .padding(5)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding(.top, 10)
            }
    }
}
```

And than I put it into Content View:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userInfo: UserInfo = UserInfo()
    var body: some View {
        
    NewView()
    
    }
}
```

The button stops working... I assume that both of those views conform to the ObservableObject. When it is changed ContentView should update, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two unrelated `UserInfo` objects. When you use `@StateObject` you are saying that you create and own the object and you'll give that object to other things that need it.

To fix the problem you should only create one `UserInfo` in `ContentView` and inject that downhill into `NewView`

```
struct NewView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userInfo: UserInfo
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("\(userInfo.test)")
            Button(action: {
                self.userInfo.test = "passed"
            }) {
                Text("Log in")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NewView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let userInfo: UserInfo = UserInfo()
        NewView(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

and

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var userInfo: UserInfo = UserInfo()
    var body: some View {
        NewView(userInfo: userInfo)
    }
}
```

Here you give the `UserInfo` downhill to `NewView`.

Possibly if you want everything in the hierarchy to have access to `UserInfo` using `@EnvironmentObject` would be better but that's another topic.

Comment: works fine. Thanks. I will read about EnviromentObject.

Comment: Heldan, please thank Warren Burton by accepting the answer if it is correct.